# How can i fix UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning when connecting mongoose with node.js?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

i want to add a collection named cats in the mongoose database , but it shows this  UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning

[image]

here is the code:

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
mongoose.set('useNewUrlParser', true);
mongoose.set('useFindAndModify', false);
mongoose.set('useCreateIndex', true);
mongoose.set('useUnifiedTopology', true);

mongoose.connect("mongod://localhost/cat_app");

var catSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    age: Number,
    temperament: String
});

var Cat = mongoose.model("Cat" , catSchema);

var george = new Cat({
    name: "george",
    age: 11,
    temperament: "grouchy"
});

george.save(function(err, cat){
    if(err){
        console.log("something went wrong!" + err);
    } else{
        console.log("added a new cat to the database!");
        console.log(cat);
    }

});
```

Comment: `mongod:` Spelling matters in programming https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/

Comment: thanks alot @CertainPerformance , it helped, just a spelling mistake

Comment: Consider deleting the question, since it was just a typo, which is off-topic - it won't be of any use to future readers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the below code:

```
    const mongoose = require('mongoose');
    mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/database_name",{ useNewUrlParser: true 
    ,useUnifiedTopology: true} );
```